# If an ID has at least one record satisfying a where clause then exclude it from the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to write a SQL select query which selects only those records for which there is no entry beyond a certain date.

The only workaround I have found so far is to extract the IDs with entries past the date then create a new select statement to exclude these IDs.

To illustrate, I wanted to select only those that have not taken up a sport since 2015:
[problem illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3fZw.png)

The output of this would be Person ID 1 and Person ID 3.

A query such as

```
SELECT [Person ID] WHERE [Date Taken Up] < 2015
```

Would return all 4 persons as they have all taken up a sport before 2014 which is not what I want.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: @Duncan This will throw an error .

Comment: @sagi, yes I know, that's why I said it probably has to be structured  as two selects, one to get the max date for each person id and then select from that the ones where the max date is before the cutoff. However Lamak's answer is probably better so I'll remove my comment.

Comment: Your query was fine, just instead of using the `WHERE` you needed to use the `HAVING` clause. @Duncan

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
                 WHERE [Date Taken Up] >= 2015
                 AND [Person Id] = A.[Person Id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In natural language, you want to select Person IDs except those that satisfy a given search condition. Here's a translation into SQL:

```
SELECT [Person ID]
  FROM YourTable 
EXCEPT
SELECT [Person ID]
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE [Date Taken Up] < 2015;
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that's worked perfectly :) I was struggling to frame the question but realize now where I was going wrong (still a bit new to SQL).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Person ID] FROM YourTable WHERE [Date Taken Up] < 2015
```